# PHP __sleep() not working with APC

Tags: php, object, apc

I have a problem with `__sleep()` function.

This is the code I'm using. If I remove `__sleep()` function from class then everything works as expected.

```
class Test {
    private $name;

    function setName($value){
        $this->name = $value;
    }

    function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    /* Works good without this function */
    public function __sleep() {
        echo 'Sleep';
    }
}

$obj = new Test;
$obj->setName('Juris');

apc_store('test', $obj);

$objAPC = apc_fetch('test');

// Output = Juris    
echo $obj->getName();
// No output and "Call to a member function getName() on a non-object" if __sleep() function is in class. Otherwise output = Juris
echo $objAPC->getName();
```

Why is this code not working? Are there any limitations with using APC and `__sleep()`?

PHP version: 5.3.14

APC version: 3.1.10

**UPDATE from answer:**

This will work if I change `__sleep()` function to this

```
public function __sleep() {
    return array('name');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic __sleep() method must return an array of property names that should be serialized, you're returns nothing.

Quoting from the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep) (my emphasis):

> It can clean up the object and **is supposed to return an array with the
>   names of all variables of that object that should be serialized**. If
>   the method doesn't return anything then NULL is serialized and
>   E_NOTICE is issued.

Comment: Thank you. Was reading the manual 10 times and did not notice that.